# Why does one get more upvotes without getting the corresponding points?

Tags: bug, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

I am getting more up votes on one of my answers and I am not getting the corresponding points! For example, I have 16 up votes with only 80 points. Can someone explain this? Thank you.

Comment: Rep cap?  Have you received 200 rep in the last day?

Comment: @ScottH.: Yes I did.

Comment: Then that's why :). Reputation is capped at +200/day.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: Congratulations on the good day!

Comment: @ScottH.: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your [reputation history](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/35472/mhenni-benghorbal?tab=reputation), I see that you have hit the rep cap for today. This occurs once you gain 200 reputation in one day. Once you hit the rep cap, you can only gain reputation from accepts and bounties until the day ends.

Comment: I see. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: OTOH, it seems OP had already gotten "Mortarboard", so this certainly isn't his first time to cap...

Comment: @J.M. But it may be his first time going over.